# Stuck with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, api, mapbox

RESOLVED.
Ensure you are entering the correct and valid information to fetch lat and lon.

Trying to use Mapbox to pass in users' coordinates which are grabbed from another API. Struggling with how to pass the coordinates into mapbox to change the map position.

Existing code:

JS

```
// Store holders for data
document.getElementById('ipHere');
document.getElementById('countryHere');
document.getElementById('countryCode');
document.getElementById('countryFlag');
document.getElementById('provider');


const api = 'https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=a518de11479a7774cc93a2ff374998f2dc01b4c7dfdc7f40a3abfd2c';
fetch(api)
.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})

.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})

.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    // Choosing data from the API
    const {ip} = data;
    const {country_name} = data;
    const {country_code} = data;
    const {emoji_flag} = data;
    const {name} = data.asn;
    const {latitude, longitude} = data;

    console.log(longitude, latitude);
    // Setting data from API to a DOM element
    ipHere.textContent = ip;
    countryHere.textContent = country_name;
    countryCode.textContent = country_code;
    countryFlag.textContent = emoji_flag;
    provider.textContent = name;

});

// For the map
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2hhZmZleGQiLCJhIjoiY2tvb3JtZXkzMGVoOTJ6cGNzcnpiY3FhbyJ9.uw49z7s69q2Igcpi5sWcIQ';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // Container ID
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // Map style to use
center: [{longitude}, {latitude}], // Starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 12, // Starting zoom level
})
```

Looking to pass the users long and lat to mapbox to then load the map at that location. Would appreciate some help!

Comment: Is `[{longitude}, {latitude}]` your actual code or some sort of template? Otherwise try `center: [longitude, latitude]`, as it needs to be an array of numbers, not an array of objects with keys of long and lat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by moving the `mapboxgl` section inside the `then` call and changing `[{longitude}, {latitude}]` to `[longitude, latitude]`

```js
const api = 'https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=a518de11479a7774cc93a2ff374998f2dc01b4c7dfdc7f40a3abfd2c';
fetch(api)
.then(response => {
    return response.json();
})

.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
})

.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // Choosing data from the API
    const {ip} = data;
    const {country_name} = data;
    const {country_code} = data;
    const {emoji_flag} = data;
    const {name} = data.asn;
    const {latitude, longitude} = data;

    console.log(longitude, latitude);
    // Setting data from API to a DOM element
    ipHere.textContent = ip;
    countryHere.textContent = country_name;
    countryCode.textContent = country_code;
    countryFlag.textContent = emoji_flag;
    provider.textContent = name;
    // For the map
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2hhZmZleGQiLCJhIjoiY2tvb3JtZXkzMGVoOTJ6cGNzcnpiY3FhbyJ9.uw49z7s69q2Igcpi5sWcIQ';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map', // Container ID
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // Map style to use
      center: [longitude, latitude], // Starting position [lng, lat]
      zoom: 12, // Starting zoom level
    });


})
```

codepen example: https://codepen.io/jeroenverfaillie/pen/PoRBZJG

Make sure you've disabled adblock, otherwise the api call might be blocked by the client.